# How to change the control bar color in Fancybox 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox

I want to change the color of the controls of my Fancybox 3 gallery, as the default is barely readable.

I already loaded a separate Fancybox stylesheet, that allows me to change the color of the background. I can not find a way to change the color of the controls using the same method, though.

Contents of fancybox.css:

```css
.fancybox-bg {
    background: #ccc;
}

.fancybox-is-open .fancybox-bg {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Comment: if you are overriding standard styles, did you try using `!important` for instance: `.fancy-bg { background: red !important; }`

Comment: Check the order of `fancybox.css` and your custom css files.

Comment: Would you share your thoughts on what colors you find more readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be more specific about what color you would like to change, but if you refer to buttons in the top right corner, then you can do that by tweaking `.fancybox-button` class, example:

```
.fancybox-button {
  background: red;
  color: #fff; /* Tip: This will change icon color */
  padding: 0; /* Tip: Change padding to resize icon */
}
```

Important: Make sure you add your CSS customization code AFTER including fancybox.css

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.fancybox-bg {
    background: #ccc !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the parent element or class or id to override plugin css.
For example

div .fancybox-bg{...}
or
.class_name .fancybox-bg{...}